# How can I insert into a Bigquery table with structs and arrays from table with slightly different structs and arrays

Tags: google-bigquery, insert

I need to insert into a BIGQUERY table with a schema like this

```
Col1 - string
col2 - record
col2.col_a - string
col2.col_b - Record Repeated
col2.col_b_fld1 - string
col2.col_b.fld2 - string
col2.col_c string
col2.col_d - record repeated
col2.col_d.fld1 - string
col3 - record repeated
```

from a table with a schema like this

```
Col1 - string
col2 - record
col2.col_a - string
col2.col_b - Record Repeated
col2.col_b_fld1 - string
col2.col_b.fld2 - string
col2.col_c string
col3 - record repeated
```

ie missing the 'col_d' element in col2 (its billing data which has changed format !)

can anyone assist - I have tried all sorts of Struct and array formats and none seem to work

Google seem to have changed the format of my billing export and included an extra array within a struct in the middle of the data and I am trying to combine several billing exports into one (some old and some new) and failing.

I need to do the insert so that I can combine data from old style tables into 1 which can then be added to

Answer (score 2):

sorted it -
I needed to 'select' the struct within the struct
so my query looks like this
insert Newtable
(select col1, struct(col2.col_a, array(select as struct newcol2_b.fld1, newcol2_b.fld2 from unnest(col2.col2_b) as newcol2_b), col2.col_c, [("","")]), col3)